# Double change for frame of reference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Is it possible to change frame of references 2 times? Being more specific, if I have a Hamiltonian $$H = H_0 + H_a + H_b,$$
i can go in the interaction picture and have my new interaction picture hamiltonians
$$H_a^i + H_b^i$$
The time evolution operator now would be
$$U(t) = U_0(t) U^i(t)$$
Where $U_0(t)$ is the time evolution operator given by the Hamiltonian that generated the transformation, and the other is the one generated by the Hamiltonians in the interaction picture. Can I now generalise and assume that I could use $H_a^i$ to generate another transformation, that gives $H_b^{i_2}$ and have the final evolution operator in the Schroedinger picture to be
$U(t) = U_0(t) U^i_a(t) U_b^{i_2}$?

Comment: Can you say what each of your $U(t)$ operators are in terms of an exponential with a Hamiltonian in it? I'm not very clear on for example $U^i(t)$. Is it supposed to have just the interaction hamiltonians or the complete $H$? None of the Hamiltonians in the exponent are in the interaction picture btw, they are just Schrödinger picture Hamiltonians (just the operators without time evolution)